# member cannot be defined in the current scope

Tags: c++

I am currently doing a checker for the top level domains of email addresses. In order to check, I am comparing it to a list that is a text file. I want to import the list into a static map container. However, when I try to instantiate it, it says that it cannot be defined in the current scope. Why is that?

This is some my header file:

```
    class TldPart {
    public:
        static void LoadTlds();
    private:
        static map<string,bool> Tld;
    }
```

Here is the implementation in the cpp:

```
    void TldPart::LoadTlds()
    {
        map<string,bool> Tld;
        ...
    }
```

It is telling me that ValidTld cannot be defined in the LoadTlds function.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static members of a class exist outside of an object. You should define and initialize static member outside of the class.

Here we define and initialize a static class member:

**header-file:**

```
#pragma once

#include <map>
#include <string>

class TldPart {
public:
    static void LoadTlds();
private:
    static std::map<std::string, bool> tld;
};
```

**your cpp-file:**

```
#include "external.h"

std::map<std::string,bool> TldPart::tld;

void TldPart::LoadTlds()
{
    tld.insert(std::make_pair("XX", true));
}
```

And don't forget semicolon at the end of the class.

EDIT: You can provide in-class initializers for static members of const integral type or static members that are constexprs and has literal type.

Comment: Good, but `#pragma once` and `#include "stdafx.h"` are nonstandard, and don't do anything here anyway.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Right, but I cannot be sure the author included that, considering he missed a semicolon.